# ulimit configuration explanation of different types

Tags: linux, ulimit

I am setting several ulimits (system is rhel 7.5) and i can't find any clarification on the values of `type`. From inside the `/etc/security/limits.conf` i get that type can get two values while in the configuration example that file contains has 3 values:

1. soft
2. hard
3. - (dash)

In the example from file below **@students** there is a type **-**.

Question when **- (dash)** is used?

```
    ....
    #<type> can have the two values:
    #        - "soft" for enforcing the soft limits
    #        - "hard" for enforcing hard limits
    .....
    #<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
    #*               soft    core            0
    #*               hard    rss             10000
    #@student        hard    nproc           20
    #@faculty        soft    nproc           20
    #@faculty        hard    nproc           50
    #ftp             hard    nproc           0
    #@student        -       maxlogins       4
    .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find answers in [man limits.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf)

```
<type>
hard
for enforcing hard resource limits. These limits are set by the superuser and enforced by the Kernel. The user cannot raise his requirement of system resources above such values.
soft
for enforcing soft resource limits. These limits are ones that the user can move up or down within the permitted range by any pre-existing hard limits. The values specified with this token can be thought of as default values, for normal system usage.
-
for enforcing both soft and hard resource limits together.
Note, if you specify a type of '-' but neglect to supply the item and value fields then the module will never enforce any limits on the specified user/group etc. .
```